# Solving simple linear function in R

Tags: r, equation-solving

I have two simple equations.

```
     46.85 = r/k
     8646.709 = r/(k^2)
```

I am trying to solve for r and k and I tried setting up my equations as follows

```
model <- function(r,k) { c(46.85 = r/k, 
                       8646.709 = r/(k^2))}

ss <- multiroot(f = model, start = c(1, 1))
```

I am seeing some errors. Not sure where I am going wrong. Any advice on how to solve this equation for `r` and `k` is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you report the errors you obtain and packages you're using? multiroot() doesn't seem to be a function of base R...

Comment: The function is not linear; it is nonlinear. You can also solve this manually. See my answer. And you really should show the package you are using. I can guess.

Comment: @Bhas, my mistake you are correct it is non linear I was not thinking right.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using package `rootSolve`. The way you have specified your function is very wrong. You should have something like this

```
library(rootSolve)

model <- function(par) { 

    y <- numeric(2)
    r <- par[1]
    k <- par[2]

    y[1] <- 46.85 - r/k
    y[2] <- 8646.709 - r/(k^2)

    y
}
```

and then try this:

```
xstart <- c(1,1)
multiroot(model, xstart)
```

`multiroot` cannot find a solution. Output is

```
$root
[1] -203307927145 -204397435886

$f.root
[1]   45.85533 8646.70900

$iter
[1] 3

$estim.precis
[1] 4346.282
```

which is not a solution. Trying other starting values doesn't help.

I will demonstrate two ways of solving your system of equations: manually and using another package.
You can solve your equations manually like this:
From the first equation we have

```
r <- 46.85 * k
```

Substitute this in the second equation and simplfy and we get

```
k <- 46.85/8646.709
```

Insert the value found for `k` in the equation for `r`
and display the values for `r` and `k`

```
> r
[1] 0.2538448
> k
[1] 0.005418246
```

and then run the model function like this

```
model(c(r,k))
```

giving output

```
[1] 0 0
```

The **second method** involves using another package namely `nleqslv`.
It has more methods and strategies for finding solutions of system of nonlinear equations.
It also has a testfunction for investigating which method and/or strategy works. Like this

```
library(nleqslv)
xstart <- c(1,1)
testnslv(xstart,model)
```

Output is

```
Call:
testnslv(x = xstart, fn = model)

Results:
    Method Global termcd Fcnt Jcnt Iter Message     Fnorm
1   Newton  cline      1   68   13   13   Fcrit 1.009e-19
2   Newton  qline      1   75   17   17   Fcrit 4.896e-19
3   Newton  gline      3   90   11   11 Stalled 2.952e+07
4   Newton pwldog      1   91   50   50   Fcrit 2.382e-22
5   Newton dbldog      1   97   54   54   Fcrit 3.243e-22
6   Newton   hook      1   72   41   41   Fcrit 6.359e-21
7   Newton   none      5    1    2    2 Illcond 3.738e+07
8  Broyden  cline      2   88    4   20   Xcrit 8.744e-14
9  Broyden  qline      2  153    4   32   Xcrit 1.111e-11
10 Broyden  gline      3  156    7   16 Stalled 1.415e+07
11 Broyden pwldog      4  261   13  150 Maxiter 1.462e+03
12 Broyden dbldog      4  288   20  150 Maxiter 1.618e+03
13 Broyden   hook      1  192    7   90   Fcrit 1.340e-22
14 Broyden   none      5    2    1    3 Illcond 3.738e+07
```

Read the help page for function `nleqslv` from start to finish to see what the methods and global columns mean. From the output it seems that the Broyden method is not very successful.
You can also see that a standard Newton method (with `none` in the `global` column) cannot find a solution.
So let's try the `cline` global strategy in a call to `nleqslv`.

```
nleqslv(xstart,model,method="Newton",global="cline")
```

with output

```
$x
[1] 0.253844844 0.005418246

$fvec
[1] 8.100187e-13 4.492904e-10

$termcd
[1] 1

$message
[1] "Function criterion near zero"

$scalex
[1] 1 1

$nfcnt
[1] 68

$njcnt
[1] 13

$iter
[1] 13
```

Comparing the solution found with the manually calculated solution shows that `nleqslv` found the solution.

Comment: Why do you say `multiroot` can't find a solution?  I think you just need to structure the equations properly.  In my answer, the solution using `multiroot` matches your solutions.

Comment: How nice. I said that obviously because of the way the equations were written. Of course rewriting may/did help but not always. But in this case a direct manual solution was also possible.

Comment: Additionally: But in your reformulation c(0,0) is also a solution but it is **not** in the original formulation. So rewriting may not be a good idea in all cases.

Comment: @Bhas, this is super cool I did not know about, `nleqslv` library. I will definitely look into it more deeper.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `rootSolve` package with  a little restructuring of the equations:

```
library(rootSolve)

model <- function(x) {  
  F1 <- x[1] - 46.85*x[2]
  F2 <- x[1] - 8646.709 * (x[2]^2)
  c(F1 = F1, F2 = F2)
}

ss <- multiroot(f = model, start = c(1, 1))
```

Considering `x[1]` as `r` and `x[2]` as `k`, this gives :

```
 print(ss)

#$root
#[1] 0.253844844 0.005418246
#
#$f.root
#           F1            F2 
#-2.164935e-15 -6.191553e-11 
#
#$iter
#[1] 13
#
#$estim.precis
#[1] 3.095885e-11
```

Comment: See the comment made by me as reply to @Aramis7d comments. In your reformulation c(0,0) is a solution but that is **not** a solution of the original system.

Comment: @Aramis7d, now I know what I was doing wrong. Thanks Aramis.

Comment: @Science11 glad to be of help. please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)